# Internal Server Error after i change .htaccess for gzip compression

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip

So today i did my google speed insight test and the gzip compression was recommend. 
so i know that my hosting a linux Apache so i put that code in it:

```
###################
# GZIP COMPRESSION #
####################
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-     javascript application/x-httpd-php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

And now i get:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Here is what my .htaccess look like at the moment when it work

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now im totally confuse. I transfer the website today ( url change + export database ) not sure if the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[internal]` and `[server]` (and presumably `[error]`, though IIRC that tag is blacklisted) together don't mean the same thing as `[internal-server-error]`.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: And as for your problem, ISEs are **always** accompanied by entries in the error log.  View the error log for the site, and you will discover what the problem is.